# How to derive this polylogarithm identity (involving Bernoulli polynomials)?

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, polylogarithm, bernoulli-polynomials, derivation-of-formulae

How can one derive the following identity, found [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Polylogarithm#Relationship_to_other_functions), relating the polylogarithm functions to Bernoulli polynomials?

$$\operatorname{Li}_n(z)+(-1)^n\operatorname{Li}_n(1/z)=-\frac{(2\pi i)^n}{n!}B_n\!\left(\frac12+\frac{\ln(-z)}{2\pi i}\right).$$

I'm curious because this formula turned out to be useful for me, but I have no idea where it comes from.

**Edit:** If there is a complicated proof of the above formula, but also a simpler procedure for deriving the formula for specific $n$, I would be interested in seeing both of these. I'm also only interested in the case where $z$ is real and negative.

Comment: I would put $z =  - {\rm e}^{2\pi {\rm i}w}$ with $ - \frac{1}{2} < w < \frac{1}{2}$, use the series expansion of $\operatorname{Li}_n$ and compare the left-hand side with [$(24.8.3)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/24.8.E3). The latter follows from [$(24.2.3)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/24.2.E3) via Cauchy's formula and the residue theorem.

Comment: @Gary Does (24.8.3) also hold for $x\in\mathbb C$? I would like $z$ (in the formula in my post) to be real (and negative), which will require using complex $x$ in (24.8.3). Specifically, on the right side we have $B_n(\frac12+ai)$, with $a\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Both sides are analytic on the plane with a cut from $0$ to positive infinity. You can use analytic continuation to extended the identity to this larger domain.